# How to share common function between server and client using node.js

Tags: node.js, prototype, require

Following are the structure of my application

[image]

Inside **prototype.js** file i have following code:

```
(function(exports) {
    exports.foo = function() {
        return 'bar';
    };
})((typeof process === 'undefined' || !process.versions) ? window.common = window.common || {} : exports);
```

**app.js contains**

```
var express = require('express'),app = express(),server = require('http').createServer(app),io = require('socket.io').listen(server),port = 3000,path = require('path');
var common = require('common/prototype');
console.log(common.foo());
// listening to port...
server.listen(port);
//Object to save clients data
var users = [];
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile('/public/index.html');
});
```

**index.html** contains

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Socket.io Demo</title>   
</head>
<body>    
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="/common/prototype.js"></script>  
    <script>
    alert(window.common.foo()); //This line will gives me an error TypeError: window.common is undefined
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now i would like to print 
**Hello, I am bar** from server and client as well.

Now i am able to print from server side using following line

```
var common = require('common/prototype');
console.log(common.foo());
```

**But could not able to show alert on client side**. could you please help me to find the root cause for the issue.

Comment: Did you mistakenly type `generic.js` instead of `prototype.js`? Also check in network tab in firebug if `prototype.js` is loading properly.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is that when  you do `<script src="/common/prototype.js"></script>` in your HTML the file won't be fetched because the Express static middleware is only looking for files under your public folder.

A quick way to test this is to copy your `prototype.js` to your `javascript` folder inside `public`. Then update your script tag to reference the file as follows `<script src="/javascripts/prototype.js"></script>`

The thing to remember is that the JavaScript files that live under node_modules are not automatically available to the browser.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it is not resolve my problem. I don't want to duplicate js code for client and server. I have common function which will be used both side (server and client), but i don't know where should i put my js file to from where server and client can be access.